# is applicationWillResignActive the earliest indicator we get that an app is becoming inactive?

Tags: ios, avplayer, appdelegate, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //pause AVPlayer if music is playing
}
```

However upon pressing the Home button the music doesn't actually stop until the iOS has returned to the home screen (after the app-closing animation). I'm wondering if there's a way to make the music stop sooner than this, before the iOS does the app-closing animation.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same issue.